# In my case, I wonder which one will have better performance? Or are they the same?

Tags: performance, groovy

My current Groovy code is as below:

```
def taskResult = taskList.filter(it.state == "ready");
for(def task in taskResult){
    def process = processAPI.getProcess(task.processId);
    // "dateFrom" is a search option in String
    if(process.endDate?.format(dateFormat2) <= dateFrom){
        continue;
    }
    if(process.objectId <= 0){
        continue;
    }
    //Do something
}
```

I consider it is not having good performance if the data is large, as it basically get all valid data, loop through them to filter further.

I think of the below code:

```
def taskResult = taskList.filter(
    it.state == "ready"
    && processAPI.getProcess(it.processId).endDate?.format(dateFormat2) > dateFrom
    && processAPI.getProcess(it.processId).objectId > 0
);
for(def task in taskResult){
    //Do something
}
```

This look more neat, but I wonder if it is actually improve the performance? Or is it worse as it call the process searching function twice?

Comment: @ou_ryperd my test data is not really that big to actually be able to compare the performance. And the system that I maintain have no function to generate the data, so creating them will quite the pain.

Comment: @ou_ryperd This question contains hypothetical code and is *not* welcome on Code Review.

Comment: Depending on some specifics of the input, either of those could potentially be more performant than the other.  Separate from that, your 2nd example is better for numerous reasons unrelated to runtime performance.